# Удалить управляющие последовательности из строки на PHP

Tags: php, строки

есть ли в PHP встроенная функция для удаления управляющих символов или надо писать велосипеды?

Answer (score 2):

```
$string = "Test\r\n\t string\011\r\t\n\040input éñó (\a\cb\e - not stripped)";
$result = preg_replace('/\p{Cc}+/u', '', $string);
echo "<pre>{$string}</pre><hr><pre>{$result}</pre>";
```

**Где:**
**\p{Cc}** - управляющие символы
**u** - указатель на то, что работаем с utf-8 строкой.
**Требуемая версия php 5.1.0 +**

**Вывод:**

```
Test
     string 
    
 input éñó (\a\cb\e - not stripped)

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Test string input éñó (\a\cb\e - not stripped)
```

**[Свойства Unicode-символов](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/regexp.reference.unicode.php)**